# T-SQL :: Error converting data type varchar to numeric when changing 1 to 0.5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, type-conversion

I'm writing a complex T-SQL query with `CASE` that will help me calculate how much time it will take me to migrate databases based on the size of each database:

```
SELECT 
    ProductVersion
    ,CompatibilityLevel
    ,convert(numeric(10,2), substring([Size], 1, (len([Size]) - 3))) as [Size in MB]
    ,CASE
        when ProductVersion < '11%' THEN 1
        when ProductVersion = NULL then 1
        ELSE ''    
    END  + 
    CASE
        when CompatibilityLevel < '110' then 1
        when CompatibilityLevel = NULL then 1
        ELSE ''
    END  + 
    CASE
        when  convert(numeric(10,2), substring([Size], 1, (len([Size]) - 3))) < 100.00 THEN 1 -- Here is the problem
        ELSE ''
    END AS [Hours of work]
FROM MyDatabaseList
```

All good, it works when I set 1 hour of work for every database which has less then 100.00 MB.

[image]

Also all other values are summed and in the Hours of work column you can see numbers like `0`, `1`, `3`, `2`...
This means SQL Server is calculating values. All good.

But well, telling to my manager that I have to work 1 hour for a database that only has 100.00 MB of size is ridiculous.

Let's change the line:

```
    when  convert(numeric(10,2), substring([Size], 1, (len([Size]) - 3))) < 100.00 THEN 1
```

and let's put `0.5` instead of `1`:

```
    when  convert(numeric(10,2), substring([Size], 1, (len([Size]) - 3))) < 100.00 THEN 0.5
```

...and bang - I get this error:

[image]

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Questions:

1. Why this error now?
2. Why it was successfully calculating before and now needs a datatype somewhere?
3. What change do I have to add to my query?
4. Why it says on `Line 1`? The error must be on `Line 16`, right?

Comment: Suggested reading: [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It explains what happens when you combine data types in an expression, e.g. a `case` which will return _one_ data type regardless of which case value is returned.

Comment: Amazing @HABO, does it means that `datetime2` can be converted to `datetime` but not the other way around?

Comment: The table at [CAST and CONVERT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-conversions) documents the _implicit_ and _explicit_ conversions supported by SQL Server. Data type precedence defines what happens _implicitly_ when two different data types meet, e.g. `1 / 2.0`. Play with `select 1 as Value, SQL_Variant_Property( 1, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType, SQL_Variant_Property( 1, 'Scale' ) as Scale, SQL_Variant_Property( 1, 'Precision' ) as Precision;` and replace `1` with `2.0`, `1 / 2` or `1 / 2.0` to see what happens.

Comment: The data type precedence list says `datetime2` is 5 and `datetime` is 6. The higher precedence is 5 (From the people who brought you `ERROR_SUCCESS`.), so if you had an expression that combined the two types the _implicit_ winner would be `datetime2`: `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate(); declare @Now2 as DateTime2 = GetDate() + 500; select case when DatePart( second, GetDate() ) % 2 = 0 then @Now else @Now2 end as Nowish, SQL_Variant_Property( case when DatePart( second, GetDate() ) % 2 = 0 then @Now else @Now2 end, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType;` _always_ returns a `datetime2`.

Comment: You can use `cast` or `convert` if you need to go from a `datetime2` to a `datetime`, but that is explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the conversion is happening in the statement that starts in line 1.

As for why, it's because `''` *cannot* be converted to a `numeric` but it can be converted to an `int`.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(2,1),'')
--Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
GO
SELECT CONVERT(int,'')
--
GO
```

You were previously converting it to an `int` (the literal `1` is an `int`). Get out of the habit of declaring `''` for a number; it is by definition **not** a number, it is a zero length string. If you want zero, then use `0`.